# ASPNET Identity 2.0 - UserManager.Update not working on some users

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity

I have an easy webapi endpoint that just update FirstName and LastName of an identity user:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateUser(UpdateUserBindingModel updateUserModel)
        {
            
            try
            {

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

                var user = this.AppUserManager.FindById(updateUserModel.Id);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    user.Email = updateUserModel.Email;
                    user.FirstName = updateUserModel.FirstName;
                    user.LastName = updateUserModel.LastName;

                    this.AppUserManager.Update(user);
                    return Ok("");
}
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("ERROR001 on UpdateUser");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }

        }
```

I have checked in debug and I can grant you that the execution is working well for all the users but
for some of them the update is not reflected to database data...

I have also tryed to check on SQL PROFILER and for those Users I cannot find any UPDATE command logged.

What can be the problem ?
Its the first time that happens one thing like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem !!!

It was trickly: in test environment I have set all the email addresses of ASPNETUSERS table to "myemail@gmail.com" in order to test email notifications.

This actually has invalidated the aspnet identity with the result that no update on db was done when calling UserManager.Update(user) and no error was returned.

Hope it can help, I have spent 4h debugging this problem